# SQL Statement with a Select Statement Inside a Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a more efficient way to write the following PLSQL statement? It seems inefficient to me to have the SQL statement nested inside the where clause.

```
SELECT REQ_ID
FROM REQUESTS R
WHERE P_REQ_ID IS NULL AND 
      EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM REQUESTS
        WHERE P_REQ_ID = R.REQ_ID
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
Select Distinct rParent.REQ_ID
From REQUESTS rParent
Inner Join REQUESTS rChild On rChild.P_REQ_ID = rParent.REQ_ID
Where rParent.P_REQ_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Did you actually compare performance/resource usage for both Selects? I doubt that `join`  plus `distinct` is more efficient than `exists`, in fact the optimizer might do the same execution plan for both...

Comment: Yes, obviously. as per my query understanding, table has request_id with its child entity. Parent record will have p_req_id = NULL and its child have recursive parent Request_id. So, in that case exists will give much read compare to INNER JOIN, If table is indexed very well.

Comment: @JERRY What do you mean by "much read compare"?

Comment: @dnoeth The EXISTS query takes 378 msecs. The join plus distinct takes 608 msecs. But, the EXISTS query is nested inside a select statement in a larger query. And, the larger query is faster as far as I can tell right now.

Comment: Ok, then the optimizer might create a different plan, e.g. executing an additional  join before the Exists.

Comment: @ADH I was agree with your given solution. Performance of JOIN & Exists is always depends on size of data, nature of data and Indexes. behavior could be different always.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an INNER JOIN but not sure if it will change your performance significantly:

```
SELECT R.REQ_ID
FROM REQUESTS R
INNER JOIN (SELECT distinct P_REQ_ID 
        FROM REQUESTS) R2
ON R.P_REQ_ID IS NULL AND 
        R2.P_REQ_ID = R.REQ_ID
```